# Are group subscriptions automatically handled on Reconnect?

Tags: signalr

I have a chat room using SignalR Hub for its messaging.  Occasionally I get reports from users where it 'freezes'.  Now this can be interpreted as no messages are coming through, I suspect as they have been dropped from a group.

My question is, does the connection get re-subscribed back into its groups automatically, or do you have to do something yourself in the Reconnect method:

```
public Task Reconnect(IEnumerable<string> groups)
{
        return Clients.rejoined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in 1.0.0.0-alpha1 you can enable auto rejoining of groups by using the new [`AutoRejoiningGroupsModule`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Pipeline/AutoRejoiningGroupsModule.cs) pipeline module using the `EnableAutoRejoiningGroups` extension method for the hub pipeline you build. This feature was not available in previous versions of the framework.

So you would end up with this somewhere in your startup code:

```
GlobalHost.HubPipeline.EnableAutoRejoiningGroups();
```

**UPDATE:**

Please note that the final version of SignalR 1.0 made auto-rejoining of groups the default behavior and so `EnableAutoRejoiningGroups` was removed. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967575/enableautorejoininggroups-disappeared-in-signalr-1-0) for more details.

Comment: Hijacking with a bonus question: Should i remember to remove people from groups again or do it clear up itself when the connectionids are disconnected?

Comment: `EnableAutoRejoiningGroups()` is no longer available, and auto rejoining is the default behaviour according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967575/enableautorejoininggroups-disappeared-in-signalr-1-0

Comment: @ReginLarsen Yup, they changed it, I will update my answer so people who come across it are aware. Thanks!