# EnableAutoRejoiningGroups disappeared in SignalR 1.0

Tags: signalr

Looks like GlobalHost.HubPipeline.EnableAutoRejoiningGroups() has disappeared in 1.0 final release of SignalR.

However there is no mention of where it went in the release notes and no clue how to get this functionality back.

Anybody knows what happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found comment in the source tree:

*EnableAutoRejoining has been removed from HubPipeline. This feature is turned on by default.*

Comment: you can find that comment on release notes -> https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md

Comment: At the time I posted this it was not clear in the release notes.